# Bootsrap 4 responsive columns and hiding on mobile devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to show 2 columns of different sizes: 
8 columns and 4 columns on desktop (>=col-xl) Hide first column + show second column on entire screen (12 columns).Here is the code:

```
<div class="d-none d-xl-block col-xl-8">....</div>
<div class="col-12 col-xl-4">...</div>
```

Displays well on desktop screen, displays the same (8 + 4 instead of 0 + 12) on mobile. 
Why does it not change on galaxy / mobile debugger size in chrome?
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

That didn't work as expected due to this mistake:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

Now, when it's defined correctly, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

everything works as expected.